# Godot GDScript "too many arguments" error

Tags: godot, gdscript

I got this error in one of my gdscript scripts in a Godot project:
"Too many arguments for "get_script()" call. Expected at most 0."
For this line of code:

```
onready var coinscript = get_script("res://path/script.gd")
```

I have no idea why this error is there. Anyone do?

Answer (score 4):

The [`get_script`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_object.html#class-object-method-get-script) takes no arguments and returns the Script attached to the current object. That is, the script you are writing. Which can be useful, for example, for meta-programming.

---

However, it appears you want an script given its path. Thus, you probably want to use [`load`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_%40gdscript.html#class-gdscript-method-load) instead:

```
onready var coinscript = load("res://path/script.gd")
```

See also [`preload`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_%40gdscript.html#class-gdscript-method-preload), [`ResourceLoader.load`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_resourceloader.html#class-resourceloader-method-load), [Loading vs Preloading](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/getting_started/workflow/best_practices/logic_preferences.html#loading-vs-preloading) and [Background Loading](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/io/background_loading.html).